# run the command from a script by alertify.js. in .ctp for alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, alertify

hello I have this script [alertify](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) but when I run on my alertascompraventa.ctp not run me anything, I dont now if I'm using bad the alertify o is not correct the form to the use in the cake php.

alertascompraventa.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->hidden('id', array('value' => $this->data['Soya']['id']));
echo $this->Html->script('alertify');
echo $this->Html->css(array('alertify.core', 'alertify.default'));
 ?>




    <td><?php 
        if ($GranoSoyatm == (($TortaSolventeSoyatm*0.80)+($HarinaIntegralSoyatm*0.95)+$CascarillaSoyatm+$AceiteCrudoSoyatm+($AceiteRefinadoSoyatm*0.18))) {
            echo 'La compra de grano y produccion de Soya coinciden';
        }
        if ($GranoSoyatm < (($TortaSolventeSoyatm*0.80)+($HarinaIntegralSoyatm*0.95)+$CascarillaSoyatm+$AceiteCrudoSoyatm+($AceiteRefinadoSoyatm*0.18))) {
            echo 'La produccion de derivados '.(($TortaSolventeSoyatm*0.80)+($HarinaIntegralSoyatm*0.95)+$CascarillaSoyatm+$AceiteCrudoSoyatm+($AceiteRefinadoSoyatm*0.18)).' es mayor a la compra de grano '.$GranoSoyatm.'.';
?>
                        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
                          alertify.log("PRODUCCION BAJA."); 
                       </SCRIPT>
<?php


}
        if ($GranoSoyatm > (($TortaSolventeSoyatm*0.80)+($HarinaIntegralSoyatm*0.95)+$CascarillaSoyatm+$AceiteCrudoSoyatm+($AceiteRefinadoSoyatm*0.18))) {
            echo 'La compra de grano '.$GranoSoyatm.' es mayor a la produccion de derivados '.(($TortaSolventeSoyatm*0.80)+($HarinaIntegralSoyatm*0.95)+$CascarillaSoyatm+$AceiteCrudoSoyatm+($AceiteRefinadoSoyatm*0.18)).'.';
        }
                ?></td>
```

Comment: Do you see in a developer console that alertify.js is loaded? Or is cake pointing to the wrong direction?

Comment: Your code is a mess, fix it. And in the future use English names for variables.

Comment: Try to save all messages in one array, then just output any at the end of your page. It might be the case that the page finished loaded and the script has not. Usually jQuery's document.ready() or head.ready() get you around that. You can also use CakePHP's buffered output to make sure your script is always loaded at the end of the layout. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::script